# updating GUI elements from a different thread ? how do you usually implement it ? (GTK+ )

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, gtk

I have this application that uses threads , in one thread i have a computation that updates a global variable constantly, in another thread i'm running a GUI. Since i am still learning the mechanism of effective GUI implementation, i would like to know, how to update a textview in GUI with the value of the global variable when it is changed from the other thread.

I am interested in seeing the good practice of implementing such task. I read you can implement the signal mechanism...but how do you transfer a thread specific function to the GUI thread.

for the info, i am using:

Threads of C++11
GTK+3 for GUI

Comment: I would suppose that the change of the value on the computation thread would cause a signal to be fired which would be handled on the GUI thread.

Comment: thank you, but an example would help, how does one fire a signal in the working thread then have the GUI respond to it...

Answer (score 2):

One good approach is to add an idle handler (g_idle_add) to the GTK+ main context, the handler then runs on the main UI thread.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html GAsyncQueue is another option, put some kind of events in the queue that notify of new values. You will then need a main loop source for the queue though. There are a couple in bugzilla attached to this bug and its duplicates: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=442364
those might be a helpful starting point.

The idle handler would look like this:

```
     GSource *source;

      source = g_idle_source_new ();
      g_source_set_priority (source, priority);
      g_source_set_callback (source, function, data, notify);
      g_source_attach (source, g_main_context_get_default());
      g_source_unref (source);
```

Note that the source is attached to `g_main_context_get_default()` which is the event loop GTK uses.

There's also a `g_main_context_invoke` function which you could probably use, that will be the same as the idle handler above if called from another thread, but calls the function immediately if you are already in the main thread.

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-main-context-invoke

Here is a blog post that looks useful with more detail:
https://tecnocode.co.uk/tag/gsource/

Comment: Is there by any chance any example...the link does not provide examples.